# Get the names of the previous months with DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In a HTML table, i need to display a date(Month/Year) & the 6 previous and next months.

this code displays the actual month and year

```
    <th>
        <%= 
        String.Format("{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Now).ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year%>
    </th>
```

I can't find how to get the previous/next months and how to update the year in case the year has changed.
Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)` and `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

As has been answered, you can find the previous or next month using:

`DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)` or `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)`.

However, you can also simplify your code greatly by using this DateTime format string:

```
var theDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);  //previous month
theDate.ToString("MMMM/yyyy");
```

So in your case:

```
    <th>
        <%= String.Format("{0:MMMM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) %>
    </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
  DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
```

This will get the next month and if you swap the 1 for -1 it will return the previous month.